# Flutter SQFlite Delete Multiple by List of integer IDs

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

**SQFlite in Flutter**

Following code deletes one row by the given ID

```
Future<int> delete(int id) async {
Database db = await instance.database;
return await db.delete(myTable, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
}
```

but How to delete multiple IDs simultaneously?

I have ***variable*** list:
`List<int> toBeDeleted = [5, 4, 8, ...]`

I tried giving a list in whereArgs but it's not working. What I'm looking for is being able to "Delete Selected Multiple items at once".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the SQLite `IN` clause:

```
await db.delete(myTable, where: 'id IN (?,?,?)', whereArgs: [id1, id2, id3]);
```

Since the list size can change, having the proper number or ? can be solved using the following solution:
`List.filled(inArgsCount, '?').join(',')`

```
var list = ['5', '4', '8'];
return await db.delete('myTable',
  where: 'id IN (${List.filled(list.length, '?').join(',')})',
  whereArgs: list);
```

More information here
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md#parameters